# Tensorflow SSD model loses accuracy in other classes after training for one

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection, object-detection-api

I'm trying to improve the accuracy of the ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco model from [tensorflow's model detection zoo](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/detection_model_zoo.md) in certain classes. I began by training the model to detect chairs. I gathered my testing and training images and trained until the loss was around 1.5 and no longer decreasing, at which point it had been training for 884 steps. When I evaluated it, the model was drawing random bounding boxes around nothing in particular along with an actual correct bounding box.

[image: Visualization of chair model]

After some googling, I found out that if I add `load_all_detection_checkpoint_vars: true` to the pipeline config, the model will begin training right where the base model left off. This fixed it, and now the model successfully recognized everything in all the test images. However, when I tried runnning the model on a dataset with much more classes (one the original model performs well at), I realized that the new model failed to recognize anything in any of the pictures.

Does this make sense to anyone? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It is a well known issue with neural networks in general, that they forget things from previous learning when you start a new learning session with all new training material.

Comment: @sebrockm how can I remedy this? Or how can I take a model and improve it's precision in certain classes if that's a different problem?

Comment: If you have access to the original training data, you can mix in you new data and learn again. There's no guarantee that it will work well, though.